# Who shuts down the socket connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a server/client socket application, and from the examples on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3.aspx it appears both the server and the client shutdown and close the connections after receiving data.Is this right?
I had been using disconnect but I was unable to reopen the connection, but using the shutdown/close:

```
            if (_sender.Connected)
            {
                _sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                _sender.Close();
            }
```

seems to work fine. But should this be called on both the client (initiator) and the server(recipient) sockets?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this on the client and the server both because they both have independent resources being used. Sockets can get messy (lots of exceptions) when they shutdown so you want to make sure that you are handling the exceptions on both the client and the server too.

Comment: It seemed redundant to do this, now I know for sure I'll leave the calls in both. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which side initiates the close. If the close happens cleanly, then the other side's next read operation will read 0 bytes. If the close does not happen cleanly, then the other side's next read operation will raise an exception.

In general, it is always a good idea to expect exceptions from any socket methods (except `Close`, which won't raise exceptions except for [fatal exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)). Whenever you see an exception, just call `Close`.

P.S. `Connected` is useless, and `Shutdown` doesn't gain you anything in this case. Just call `Close`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll remove the Connected check.

Comment: Per the MSDN documentation "When using a connection-oriented Socket, always call the Shutdown method before closing the Socket. This ensures that all data is sent and received on the connected socket before it is closed."

Comment: The connected method doesn't tell you that it is currently connected but it isn't completely useless either. It does tell you if the socket was connected as of the most recent operation, granted in most cases this it is not going to be helpful.

Comment: (re. `Shutdown`): The MSDN documentation is covering the (extremely rare) case where the other side is still sending data and the receiver wants to close the socket but ensure it reads all remaining data first. To use `Shutdown` in this way, you have to shutdown only the sending stream and then continue reading. In this case, since the op is calling `Close` immediately after `Shutdown`, the call to `Shutdown` is completely unnecessary. See [shutdown docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740481.aspx) for more info.

Comment: (re. `Connected`): I've thought about this quite a bit over the years. I cannot come up with a single situation in which the return value of `Connected` is useful. People almost always attempt to use it in "is the socket currently connected" logic, which is wrong. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828917/most-awkward-misleading-method-in-the-net-api/2829016#2829016), particularly Joel Mueller's comment.

Comment: (re. Shutdown) Interestingly enough the shutdown docs that you referred to also say "To assure that all data is sent and received on a connected socket before it is closed, an application should use shutdown to close connection before calling closesocket."

Comment: @Ryan, re `Shutdown`: Yes, but read the next two paragraphs. It's clear that it's only talking about shutting down the sending stream and continuing reading. If you just call shutdown and then call closesocket, there's no benefit to calling shutdown.